# ios-charts how to make barchart correctly resize when orientation changes?

Tags: swift, constraints, orientation, ios-charts

I'm trying to make a `barchart` with ios-charts and am having an issue when if the orientation of the phone changes, the `barchartview` doesn't redraw properly to fit the screen - the graph seems to get squashed into the top 50 pixels of the view in landscape mode.

I have tried adding constraints to the `barchart` view both in code and in interface builder, but I keep hitting the same issue.

I've found a way to make it work  - removing and resetting the `barchartview` when the orientation changes like this:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    print ("orientation change")
    barChartView!.removeFromSuperview()
    barChartView  =  BarChartView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 60))
    self.view.addSubview(barChartView!)
    setChart()
}
```

but shouldn't the barcode view respond automatically to constraints set in IB? Or is there something else I need to do too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will not be refresh automatically.
Maybe you should try

```
chart.data.notifyDataChanged()
chart.notifyDataSetChanged()
chart.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: I've replaced the code I had in traitCollectionDidChange with your suggestion - still not working unfortunately..